# How to fix size/shape of output console windows in c program?

Tags: c, output, console-application

I am making one C program in which I want the function or any method to fix size of output console window. Is there any function or way in C language to perform this task?

Generally the shape of output console is rectangle but to display proper output of my program I want to fix the square shape so I want to re size the output console using the programming.

I am using GNU GCC compiler and Os is Microsoft Windows 8.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C language don't have any function to control console property but you can use windows header file to control console.

You can get a handle to the console window using [GetConsoleWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Once you have that, you should be able to resize it using [SetWindowPos](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms633545%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

You may also need to resize the buffer for the console using [SetConsoleScreenBufferSize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686044%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) prior to resizing the window.

[Visit](http://www.programming-techniques.com/2011/09/how-to-resize-console-window-using-c.html)

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no function or way in C language to alter the shape of the console.

Comment: @EugeneSh. of course there is a way to do this in C program, but there is no such function or way in C language. I see the thin red line between those two.

Comment: @SergeyA  please tell me the way I want to do this any how.